# What does Shadow Medic Proc?

Tags: the-secret-world

Does the Assault Rifle passive "Shadow Medic" proc (activate) only on direct heals, like anima shot, or does it also increase the healing of heals over time or leech?

Comment: I know for a fact that Shadow Medic does not apply to HoTs, as there is an analogue to Shadow Medic that's just for HoTs. I am curious about its effects w.r.t. Leeches, however.

Comment: The analogue would be Empowerment or something different?

Comment: Ah, no, it's Making Amends that I was thinking of. It gives +10% to HoTs, much like Shadow Medic gives +7.5% to direct healing spells. I'm inclined to believe that Shadow Medic does *not* effect leeches, though, due to the existence of Veteran (+25% boost to Leeches).